# A Potamodromous Riley

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

> My prefix may have a pout,
>   my infix, an inside lout,
>   my Suffix is a long route,
>   I am a wandering trout.

or

> My Prefix proved smokes danger,
>   my infix is to cover,
>   my Suffix founded by Gaozu,
>   I'm an Irish rover.

Comment: is it founded Gaozu or founded by Gaozu? thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My Prefix proved smokes danger,

> [Richard **Doll**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Doll)'s research helped uncover the adverse health effects of tobacco.

my infix is to cover,

> To **lag** pipes is to cover them up.

my Suffix founded by Gaozu,

> The **Han** dynasty.

I'm an Irish rover.

> **Dollaghan**, a potamodromous trout native to Northern Ireland.

My prefix may have a pout,

> A **doll**?

my infix, an inside lout,

> **lag**, a person who has been frequently convicted and sent to prison (found by JonMark Perry)

my Suffix is a long route,

> The **Ghan** is a route that crosses the entire continent of Australia, from Adelaide to Darwin.

I am a wandering trout

> **Dollaghan** again.

Comment: Lag: a person who has been frequently convicted and sent to prison.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I see... Thanks! New word for me.